On continuity of intersection and difference of sets with respect to the Hausdorff metric
Let $X$ be a complete locally compact metric space. Denote by $\mathcal{K}(X)$ the metric space of all compact subsets of $X$ endowed with the Hausdorff metric $d_H$.
It is well-known that in general the operation of taking intersection is not continuous with respect to the Hausdorff metric but all (counter-)examples (see this and this) seem to involve sets of positive codimension. I'm interested whether this continuity holds in a restricted context when no such sets are involved.
More specifically, let $A_n,B_n, A, B \in \mathcal{K}(X)$ be such that $d_H(A_n, A) \rightarrow 0$, $d_H(B_n, B) \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$, and $A\cap B$, $A_n \cap B_n$ are non-empty for all $n$,  Assume further that all of the sets $A_n,B_n, A, B, A_n \cap B_n,A\cap B$ are closures of open sets in $X$.
My first question is: is it true that $d_H(A_n \cap B_n, A\cap B) \rightarrow 0$?
My second question is, under analogous assumptions, does this continuity hold for the operation of taking difference followed by closure? More precisely, assume that $d_H(A_n, A) \rightarrow 0$, $d_H(B_n, B) \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$, $A\setminus B$, $A_n \setminus B_n$ are non-empty for all $n$, and that the sets $A_n,B_n, A, B$ are closures of open sets. Is it true that $d_H(\overline{A_n \setminus B_n}, \overline{A\setminus B}) \rightarrow 0$?
